# Adjective for large range of numbers

Tags: single-word-requests

What could be a suitable adjective for this sentence:

> The price of this product is very _______.

Meaning that the price of the same product can encompass large scope of values from one number to another one.

For example, if the price of one product, depending on the specifications, functionality and perks, is from 500 through 550 And for another one is from 400 through 1000. Then:

> The range of price of the second product is _______ than of the first one.

Large (larger) would seem like a very general adjective in this case, while I am looking for something more specific.

Comment: The trouble with many words in this area is that they default to a 'fluctuating', time-dependent reading. **Variable** is probably the best where 'ranging widely' [at a given time] is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The price range of this product is very [broad](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/broad)

*Covering a large number and wide scope of subjects.*

Also:

> The price range of the second product is *broader* than the first one.